# How can I ensure a reactjs state is updated, and then call a function?

Tags: reactjs, state, race-condition

I'm trying to use reactjs to update a state, and once it is updated fire an ajax call requesting a new page. Just before the ajax call fires an offset variable is set: `var offset = this.state.npp * this.state.page;` However I find after clickNextPage() is fired, the value of this.state.page is not updated.

I fundamentally do not understand what is happening here, this appears to be a race condition, because I watch the state change on my render() function with {this.state.page}.

**How can I ensure my this.state.page is updated, and then fire findByName()?**

```
  clickNextPage: function(event){
    console.log("clicked happend")
    page = this.state.page;
    console.log(page)
    page += 1
    console.log(page)
    this.setState({page: page});
    console.log(this.state.page)
    this.findByName()
  },
```

JS Console:

```
clicked happend
0
1
0
```

Comment: How close the code you wrote here to real code? 
Don't you have any async calls that may change `state.page` before it's updated?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous in that `this.state` will not be updated right away. The short answer to your quandary is use the callback (the second parameter to `setState`) which is invoked after the internal state is been updated. For example

```
this.setState({page: page}, function stateUpdateComplete() {
    console.log(this.state.page)
    this.findByName();
}.bind(this));
```

The longer answer is that after you call `setState`, three functions are called (see here for more details about each https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html):

- `shouldComponentUpdate` this allows you to inspect the previous and new state to determine whether the component should update itself. If you return false, the following functions are **not** executed (although the `this.state` will still be updated within your component)
- `componentWillUpdate` this gives you a chance to run any code before the new state is set internally and rendering happens
- `render` this happens between the component "will" and "did" functions.
- `componentDidUpdate` this gives you a chance to run any code after the new state is set and the component has re-rendered itself

Answer (score 2):

When calling `this.setState` the new state isn't set directly, React puts it in a pending state which by calling `this.state` can return the old state.

This is because React might batch your state updates and therefore offers no guarantee that `this.setState` is synchronous.

What you want to do is called `this.findByName()` within `componentDidUpdate`, `componentWillUpdate` or through the callback offered as a second argument to `this.setState` depending on your use case. Note that the callback to `this.setState` won't be fired until after your call has passed and the component has re-rendered itself.

Furthermore in your case you could pass a function do `this.setState` instead of doing a variable dance to increase readability.

```
this.setState(function (prevState, currentProps) {
    return {page: prevState.page + 1}
}, this.findByName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using nameless functions this code can be written in a shorter format.

```
myReactClassFunction = (param) => {
  this.setState({
    key: value,
  },
  () => this.myClassFunction());
}
```